# Convert missing to a numerical value in Julia 1

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to convert all missing values in a df to a numerical value, e.g. 0 (yes, knowing what I am doing..).

In Julia 0.6 I can write:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(
              cat = ["green","blue","white"],
              v1   = [1.0,missing,2.0],
              v2   = [1,2,missing]
            )
julia> [df[ismissing.(df[i]), i] = 0 for i in names(df)]
```

And get:

```
julia> df
3×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ cat   │ v1  │ v2 │
├─────┼───────┼─────┼────┤
│ 1   │ green │ 1.0 │ 1  │
│ 2   │ blue  │ 0.0 │ 2  │
│ 3   │ white │ 2.0 │ 0  │
```

If I try it in Julia 0.7 I get instead a very weird error:

> MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Float64 to an object
>   of type String

I can't get what I am trying to convert to a string ??? Any explanation (and workaround) ?

Comment: If I remove the `cat` column it works.. it seems that it is still trying to apply the assignment, even if the Array in case of `cat` is empty, while in Julia 0.6 it was let's say "smarter", realising that the set on where to operate was empty..

Comment: Adding `if typeof(df[i]) <: Vector{Union{Missing, Number}}` in the list comprehension doesn't work.
If I can find a way to specify the type inside the union (see [the separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118361/is-there-a-type-subtraction-operation-in-julia) I did open) I could solve the problem !

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this problem is that broadcasting mechanism has changed between Julia 0.6 and Julia 1.0 (and it is used in `insert_multiple_entries!` function in DataFrames.jl). In the end `fill!` is called and it tries to do a conversion before checking if the collection is empty.

Actually if you want to do a fully general replacement *in place* (and I understand you want to) this is a bit complex and less efficient than what you have in Base (the reason is that you cannot rely on checking types of elements in vectors as e.g. you can assign `Int` to vector of `Float64` and they have different types):

```
function myreplacemissing!(vec, val)
    for i in eachindex(vec)
        ismissing(vec[i]) && (vec[i] = val)
    end
end
```

And now you are good to go:

```
foreach(col -> myreplacemissing!(col[2], 0), eachcol(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate the answer of Bogumil Kaminski (also because now I understood the reasons behind the failure), its proposed solution fails if it happens to exists missing elements in non-numeric columns, e.g.:

```
df = DataFrame(
  cat = ["green","blue",missing],
  v1   = [1.0,missing,2.0],
  v2   = [1,2,missing]
)
```

What I can instead do is to use (either or only one, depending on my needs):

```
[df[ismissing.(df[i]), i] = 0 for i in names(df) if  typeintersect(Number, eltype(df[i])) != Union{}]
[df[ismissing.(df[i]), i] = "" for i in names(df) if  typeintersect(String, eltype(df[i])) != Union{}]
```

The advantage is that I can select the type of value I need as "missing replacement" for different type of column (e.g. 0 for a number or "" for a string).

**EDIT:**

Maybe more readable, thanks again to [Begumil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118361/is-there-a-type-subtraction-operation-in-julia):

```
[df[ismissing.(df[i]), i] = 0 for i in names(df) if  Base.nonmissingtype(eltype(df[i])) <: Number]
[df[ismissing.(df[i]), i] = "" for i in names(df) if  Base.nonmissingtype(eltype(df[i])) <: String]
```