# Is there a type subtraction operation in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Julia we have `typeintersect(Missing, Union{Missing, Float64})` (returning `Missing`).
Is it possible to get what remains instead (i.e. `Union{Missing, Float64} - Missing` returning `Float64`)?

I did try with `typesubtract(Missing, Union{Missing, Float64})` or `typecomplement(Union{Missing, Float64}, Missing)` but obviously they don't exist ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Missing` it is actually implemented in Base (but not exported) as `nonmissingtype` function. Here you have the relevant code:

```
nonmissingtype(::Type{Union{T, Missing}}) where {T} = T
nonmissingtype(::Type{Missing}) = Union{}
nonmissingtype(::Type{T}) where {T} = T
nonmissingtype(::Type{Any}) = Any
```

So this should probably solve your issue with `Missing` (just `import` this function from `Base`) and you have a template how a similar thing can be implemented for other scenarios. Please let me know if it answers what you wanted.

Comment: Just to add that `nonmissingtype` is now exported in recent Julia versions. On older versions, the Missings.jl package exports it.